# How to remove a remote ref from local copy?

Tags: git

I have a local copy of a remote repository, cloned with the `--mirror` option. The repository has many tags and branches, and consumes a lot of disk space.

In addition to that, there is another copy of that repository, cloned with the `--reference` option. This copy follows a small number of "primary" branches, branches which will unlikely disappear from the remote side.

Sometimes I need to follow yet another temporary branch from the remote side. Eventually this branch gets removed from the remote. When this happens, a `git pull` in one of the "primary" branches will fail because that temporary branch does not exist anymore.

I wonder: what is the correct way to get rid of such branch in my own copy?

Pseudo-code:

```
git clone --mirror "${remote}" "${repo_mirror}"
git clone \
  --single-branch \
  --origin "${origin}" \
  --branch "${primary}" \
  --reference "${repo_mirror}" \
  "${remote}" "${workdir}"
cd "${workdir}"
for branch in 'topicA' 'topicB' 'topicB-wip'
do
  git config --add "remote.${origin}.fetch" \
    "+refs/heads/${branch}:refs/remotes/${origin}/${branch}"
done
git fetch --all
```

In case `topicB-wip` disappears on the remote side, what is the correct way to get rid of it?

Right now the error from `git fetch --prune ${origin}` is like: `fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${branch}`

Answer (score 0):

For a mirror repository, you can use `git remote update --prune` to sync with the remote repository. New branches are created and deleted branches are removed. If there are multiple remotes in the repository, use `git remote update <remote> --prune` to specify the remote.

For a non-bare repository, `git remote update --prune` also removes the `refs/remotes/<remote>/foo` if `foo` does not exist in the remote repository.

If you want to delete the local `foo`, use `git ls-remote origin refs/heads/foo` to test if `foo` still exists in the remote repository. If it does not exist, remove the local `foo`. Note that [--exit-code](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote#Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt---exit-code) does not work as described (with 2.41.0.windows.3). With or without `--exit-code`, the exit code is always 0 no matter if the remote branch exists or not. So, I suggest

```
xxx=$(git ls-remote origin refs/heads/${branch})
if [[ "$xxx" = "" ]];then
    # the branch in the remote repository does not exist
    do something
fi
```

It's not possible to delete the current branch. You need to switch to another branch or commit first.

Comment: `git remote update --prune` does not work from `${workdir}`, it complains that `refs/heads/${branch}` does not exist.

Comment: @olh the command is not expected to touch `refs/heads/${branch}`.  What command did you use?